# Query to String from Room Database

Tags: java, android, database, android-room, dao

How do I create a query to my room database from example the SUM of a database column then convert it to a String  to then populate text fields in a different activity? I have 5 activities in my app where I wish to customise the data that is displayed but I wish to pull that data from my Room Database.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single value then you simply use an @Query annotated method that returns the the single value. e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT sum(the_column) FROM the_table")
String getTheSum();
```

- could be an integer type or decimal type, which could be more appropriate
- no need to convert to a string just retrieve as a String

  - However, you may need to format the output e.g. if you wanted a specific precision (`round(sum(the_column),2)` for 2dp). Some formats could be easier to apply outside of SQLite.

If you wanted many (0-n) you could return a List e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT  sum(the_column) FROM the_table GROUP BY the_column_or_columns_to_group_by")
List<long> getTheSums();
```

If you want to return multiple values for row then you need a POJO where there are member variables that match the column names that are output. e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT sum(the_column) AS theSum, min(the_column) AS theMin, max(the_column) AS theMax FROM the_table GROUP BY the_column_or_columns_to_group_by")
List<ThePojo> getSumMinMax();
```

Could use the POJO :-

```
class ThePojo {
   long theSum;
   long theMin;
   long theMax;
}
```

If you wanted all of the columns PLUS the additional columns you could for example have :-

```
@Query("SELECT the_table.*,sum(the_column) AS theSum, min(the_column) AS theMin, max(ithe_column) AS theMax FROM cities")
List<ThePojoPlus> getSumMinMaxPlus();
```

Could the the POJO :-

```
class ThePojoPlus {
    @Embedded
    TheTable the_table;
    @Embedded
    ThePojo pojo;
}
```

or (if there is no ThePojo class)

```
class ThePojoPlus {
   @Embedded
   TheTable the_table;
   long theSum;
   long theMin;
   long theMax;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. 

Could I just ask you to clarify how I recall the string values that we create in the Room DB structure, in various activities. For example would I just call the string in my activity.class or is there more steps involved? So in my Totals activity I wish to have a Total Hours TextView populated from sum of Totals Hours column in my database. Use @Query("SELECT sum(totalhours) FROM note")
String getTotalHours();